# I need a verb for curiosity

Tags: verbs

Please consider this scenario and help me find a verb that can be used here.

I am curious. 
I ask a question. 
The question is answered. 
My curiosity is...?

Comment: . . . satisfied.

Comment: Satisfied, sated, gone, vanished.

Comment: satiated, assuaged

Comment: You say you need a *verb* for *curiosity*, but your example and the answers assume verbs for the result of exercising curiosity successfully.  Did you instead want a verb form of "curiosity" itself?

Comment: I might say *my curiosity was answered*.

Answer (score 0):

"My curiosity is *satisfied*."
Note that that isn't a verb. It's a participle modifying 'curiosity.'